# How to get a protocol of synchronisation?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to get a protocol of all the changes that have been done in the sync session. Perfect would be to get the changes as they happen. I tried to attach to the events of the SyncOrchestrator, but could not get any filenames or what kind of changes have been made. I am trying to display something like

10:53:25 sendraw.txt uploaded

10:53:27 image.jpg deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is described here at the bottom, how to do it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887623.aspx
This does however only work for FileSyncProvider. On the other hand for my CustomProvider I can take care of the events myself. Thanks a lot to JuneT!!!

Answer (score 0):

which event did you attach to? you can easily get this from the AppliedChange event

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but could you be more specific? Where and how can I attach to this `AppliedChange` event?

I attached to the SyncOrchestrator's `StateChanged` and `SessionProgress` events, as well as to the SyncProvider's `ItemConstraint`, `ProgressChanged`, `ItemChanging` events and in none of these, I could find the attributes I needed.

Comment: destinationProvider.AppliedChange +=
            new EventHandler<AppliedChangeEventArgs>(OnAppliedChange);

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought I could just attach to the SyncOrchestrator and get the events of all Providers. But getting the ones from Filesyncprovider already is enough.